# is there any way i could minimize this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing an application which have eight advertisement boxes, the advertisement data with position is stored into the database.

the advertisement module works like first it will check if the particular position exist in the database (i.e 1 to 8) if it finds or not find it will return a Boolean accordingly.

for that reason i am using a user defined function like this.

```
 function dbgetvar($query) {
             $res = mysql_query($query);
         if( !$res) {
             trigger_error("dbget: ". mysql_error(). " in " .$query);
             return false;
             }
             if( mysql_num_rows($res) == '0' ) {
             return false;
             }
             $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
             if(!$row) return "";
             return $row;
             }
```

as i have to make the eight queries i am doing it somewhat like this.

```
$adbox1 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 1_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 1_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '1'");
$adbox2 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 2_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 2_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '2'");
$adbox3 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 3_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 3_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '3'");
$adbox4 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 4_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 4_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '4'");
$adbox5 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 5_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 5_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '5'");
$adbox6 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 6_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 6_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '6'");
$adbox7 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 7_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 7_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '7'");
$adbox8 = dbgetvar("SELECT advertisements.id as 8_id, advertisements.pic_brief as 8_brief  FROM advertisements WHERE pos = '8'");
```

and then i fetch the data like this.

```
if($adbox1){
    echo "I am found";
}
if(!$adbox1){
    echo "I am not found";
}
```

although it works fine, it is messed up and a huge queries is piled up. i want to clean and minimize it if possible.

what is your take?

Comment: I would do one query and treat the result in PHP instead of doing 8 queries. E.g `foreach($row as $ad) switch('id') ... `

Comment: A simple loop would suffice, there is really no need for a `switch` statement for this.

Comment: @Russell Dias It actually depends if Ibrahim wants to take different actions on each, or a group, of ads which we don't know.

Comment: @Ben i get the point, but the thing is i am still learning and thriving to improve my code. i am still unclear on how to use the query with foreach unless and until you explain me more deeply :)

Comment: @Ibrahim, Pies's answer is a good solution you could implement.

Comment: oh is it, thank you. although i am having some issue with his code, like if the position does not exist in the database then it is giving error. Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\website\index.php on line 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$query = "SELECT id, pic_brief FROM advertisements WHERE pos BETWEEN 1 AND 8";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$adbox = array_fill(1, 8, null);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $adbox[$row['id'] = $row;
}
```

You can access the data as `$adbox[1]['id']`/`$adbox[1]['pic_brief']` and so forth.

Edit: I've updated the code to avoid leaving empty adbox ids.

Comment: Great minds think alike ;) Although I like using `BETWEEN`, I feel it reads better.

Answer (score 3):

Round trip to the database is less efficient than a loop in PHP. So my suggestion would be to minimize it to one query (assuming pos is an integer), something like:

```
SELECT id, pic_brief, pos FROM advertisements WHERE pos BETWEEN 1 AND 8;
```

Then loop over like so to build out an array:

```
$adbox = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $adbox[$row['pos']] = $row
}
```

Do a boolean test by looking for pos as an array key:

```
if ($adbox[1]) {
  // has ad 1
}
else {
  // no ad 1
}
```

You can break it out into a function if you like on your own. But that's my take on minimizing. An added benefit is that you have access to the ad data in `$adbox`

Comment: i tried your code, it works fine for the existing position in the database, but if the value does not exist then it gives the error like this. Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\website\index.php on line 10 any idea what is happening?

Comment: I don't know what your line 10 is, so it's tough to tell. Seems like your trying to use `$adbox` for a position that doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead of `$adbox = array();` use `$adbox = array_fill(1, 8, null);` This should fix the problem.

Comment: @Pies can you please elaborate on what array_fill did and what actually happened?

Comment: You were checking for existence of array indexes just by reading them, which causes the "Undefined offset" when you hit one that's missing. To work around it you could have changed `if ($adbox[1])` to `if (isset($adbox[1]))`, or use `array_fill(1,8,null)` to pre-define the offsets by creating an array with indexes 1..8 and empty values.

Comment: PHP is a dynamically cast, weakly typed language. Although I promote clean code, this was just a notice.